# Orbeon 4.5 performance issue

Tags: orbeon

We have a little problem with Orbeon's performance. When there are like 10 people filling forms at the same time, Orbeon gets slower and slower, forms are opening so long. But it turned out that after restarting server (we use Tomcat btw.) everything just speeds up. Improvement lasts for a while and then again we have to restart Tomcat.

Do you have any idea what's the reason for such behaviour? Is there any way to maybe configure Orbeon differently to avoid restarting server constantly?

Answer (score 1):

I have two recommendations:

1. First, even if this is a long shot, if you're running Java 7, make sure you're not using the `-XX:+TieredCompilation` VM option. If you have that option, just remove it. But unless you're using certain versions of JBoss that had that option by default, it isn't likely that you manually added that option.
2. Since 4.5, we've improved the performance of Orbeon Forms in a number of places. For instance, you can see the [performance issues solved in 4.6](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+label%3APerformance+is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A4.6), and in the filter changing `4.6` with `4.7`, `.4.8`, and `4.9`, you can see all the improvements made in those versions. So my recommendation would be to upgrade to the latest release (4.9, at the time of this writing).

If none of this solves the problem, we most likely would need to work more closely with you to help on this.